# How to call multiple request in nodejs using REQUEST module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am trying to make it look better,
i'm using the request module to do an http request on the same server but a different dev id to retrieve a device value.

i have it like below, but is there an other way to include it together in one call ?

this is what i have:

```
request("http://" + DEVLINK_IP.DEVLINK_IP + ":" + DEVLINK_port.DEVLINK_port + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + addons.Lightning[1].ref2, (error, response, body) => {
            let object = JSON.parse(body);});

request("http://" + DEVLINK_IP.DEVLINK_IP + ":" + DEVLINK_port.DEVLINK_port + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + addons.Lightning[0].ref1, (error, response, body2) => {
                let object2 = JSON.parse(body2);});

request("http://" + DEVLINK_IP.DEVLINK_IP + ":" + DEVLINK_port.DEVLINK_port + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + addons.Lightning[0].ref3, (error, response, body3) => {
                let object3 = JSON.parse(body3);});

request("http://" + DEVLINK_IP.DEVLINK_IP + ":" + DEVLINK_port.DEVLINK_port + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + addons.Lightning[0].ref4, (error, response, body4) => {
                let object3 = JSON.parse(body4);});
```

here a bit of my script where i use it to:

```
// Issue the request
        request("http://" + DEV_IP.DEV_IP + ":" + DEV_port.DEV_port + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + addons.Lightning[1].ref2, (error, response, body) => {
            let object = JSON.parse(body);
        request("http://" + DEV_IP.DEV_IP + ":" + DEV_port.DEV_port + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + addons.Lightning[0].ref1, (error, response, body2) => {
                let object2 = JSON.parse(body2);
                // If there has been an error, log it
                if (error) console.error(error);
                
                
                

                message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        color: 3447003,
                        author: {
                            name: "Malosa-Lightning add-on",
                            icon_url: "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jaan-jaak/weather/256/thunder-lightning-storm-icon.png"
                        },
                        title: "Lightning Detection",
                        url: "http://google.com",
                        description: "Current live info",
                        fields: [{
                            name: "Detection:",
                            value: (object.Devices[0].status)
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Masked links",
                            value: "You can put [masked links](http://google.com) inside of rich embeds."
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Markdown",
                            value: "You can put all the *usual* **__Markdown__** inside of them."
                        }
                        ],
                        timestamp: new Date(),
                        footer: {
                            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
                            text: "© Example"
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: [The `request` module is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request); don't use it.

Comment: We have no way of knowing if the API you are calling supports passing multiple references at once.

Comment: u have a better solution ? and if so can u show me how. regards

Comment: The page I linked to in my earlier comment has pointers to alternatives.

Comment: well what i want is use 1 time that module to request a site like this [http request1, http resuest2, http request3] and so on

Comment: i know request is deprecated, but for what i'm using it it still works normal... i just need to know how i can use a multiple request, so that it checks 2 times the link in one go in a better way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it out.

I changed it to axios

when using

```
const [response1, response2 ,response3] = await axios.all([
    axios.get("WEBSITE1"), 
    axios.get("WEBSITE2"), 
    axios.get("WEBSITE3"), 
]);

console.log (response1)
console.log (response2)
console.log (response3)
```